# pyspark SparseVectors dataframe columns .dot product or any other vectors type column computation using @udf or @pandas_udf

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions, pandas-udf

> I do try to compute **.dot** product between 2 columns of a give dataframe,
> **SparseVectors** has this ability in spark already so I try to execute this in an easy & scalable way without converting to **RDDs** or to
> **DenseVectors** but i'm stuck, spent past 3 days to try find out of an
> approach and does fail, doesn't return computation for passed 2 vector
> columns from dataframe and looking for guidance on this matter,
> please, because something I'm missing here and not sure what is root cause ...
>
> For separate vectors and rdd vectors works this approach but does fail
> to work when passing dataframe column vectors, to replicate the flow
> and issues please see below, ideally would be this computation to happen in parallel since real work data is with billions or more rows (dataframe observations):

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, SparseVector
    from pyspark.sql import Row
    df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
         [["a","b","c"], SparseVector(4527, {0:0.6363067860791387, 1:1.0888040725098247, 31:4.371858972705023}),SparseVector(4527, {0:0.6363067860791387, 1:2.0888040725098247, 31:4.371858972705023})],
         [["d"], SparseVector(4527, {8: 2.729945780576634}), SparseVector(4527, {8: 4.729945780576634})],
        ], ["word", "i", "j"])

# # daframe content
df.show()
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
|     word|                   i|                   j|
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[a, b, c]|(4527,[0,1,31],[0...|(4527,[0,1,31],[0...|
|      [d]|(4527,[8],[2.7299...|(4527,[8],[4.7299...|
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+


@udf(returnType=ArrayType(FloatType()))
def sim_cos(v1, v2):
    if v1 is not None and v2 is not None:
        return float(v1.dot(v2))

# # calling udf
df = df.withColumn("dotP", sim_cos(df.i, df.j))

# # output after udf 
df.show()
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|     word|                   i|                   j|      dotP|
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|[a, b, c]|(4527,[0,1,31],[0...|(4527,[0,1,31],[0...|      null|
|      [d]|(4527,[8],[2.7299...|(4527,[8],[4.7299...|      null|
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

> Rewriting udf as lambda does work on spark 2.4.5.  Posting in case
> anyone is interested in this approach for PySpark dataframes:

```
# # rewrite udf as lambda function:
sim_cos = F.udf(lambda x,y : float(x.dot(y)), FloatType())

# # executing udf on dataframe
df = df.withColumn("similarity", sim_cos(col("i"),col("j")))

# # end result
df.show()

+---------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|     word|                   i|                   j|similarity|
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|[a, b, c]|(4527,[0,1,31],[0...|(4527,[0,1,31],[0...| 21.792336|
|      [d]|(4527,[8],[2.7299...|(4527,[8],[4.7299...| 12.912496|
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
```